# Does decreasing the size of buffer for receiving data through tcp streams increase the speed data can be transmitted

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am wondering that if I set a smaller buffer when receiving data via a tcp connection, if it will increase the two way communication speed? If I was receiving data that was <= 512 bytes, and I had my buffer set to 1024 bytes, would I get an increase in speed for any time scale with units > 10 microsecond

Comment: No, you won't make it faster. Slower, if anything. Your example is back to front from your question.

Comment: To maximize throughput, keep your socket-buffers large, and make sure your receiving-thread always calls `recv()` as quickly as possible whenever there is data available for the socket to read.  To minimize latency, turn off Nagle's algorithm and try to send as many bytes as you can with each `send()` call.